# How to do this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that I have a table with 3 fields a, b, c:

```
a b c
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
4 5 6
4 6 5
5 4 6
5 6 4
...
```

How to get only one delegate to each set of permutation (with only one query statement).
The result should be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

**Edit**: It's unsigned numbers [0-9].

Other example:

```
a b
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 2
3 4
4 3
```

The result should be:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Comment: What are the bounds for a, b and c?

Comment: Are there any maximum values or could they be anything?

Comment: Is the table guaranteed to hold all possible combinations? ie. if `1 2 3` is there, will all permutations of 1, 2 and 3 be there as well?

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed to hold all possible combinations. I forgot that. It got bugs now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table_test` 
WHERE a < b   
AND b < c
```

Comment: The way you switched the direction of your comparisons is confusing, IMO.

Comment: I think you only need 3 comparisons (`a < b` is the same as `b > a`)

Comment: you really only need two comparisons.  If a < b and b < c then a < c is a given

Comment: What if the table only contains one row: `4 3 2`, what then?

Comment: @Lasse V.Karlsen: ya, it got bugs. =.="
anyone has better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you have all permutations in the table, the query is relatively simple

```
SQL> with x as (
  2    select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 1, 3, 2 from dual
  5    union all
  6    select 2, 1, 3 from dual
  7    union all
  8    select 2, 3, 1 from dual
  9    union all
 10    select 3, 1, 2 from dual
 11    union all
 12    select 3, 2, 1 from dual
 13    union all
 14    select 4, 6, 5 from dual
 15    union all
 16    select 4, 5, 6 from dual
 17    union all
 18    select 5, 4, 6 from dual
 19    union all
 20    select 5, 6, 4 from dual
 21  )
 22  select a, b, c
 23    from x
 24   where a < b
 25     and b < c;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         4          5          6
```

If you don't know that you'll have all the permutations in the table, life is rather more complicated.  But something like this should work.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 1, 3, 2 from dual
  5    union all
  6    select 2, 1, 3 from dual
  7    union all
  8    select 2, 3, 1 from dual
  9    union all
 10    select 3, 1, 2 from dual
 11    union all
 12    select 3, 2, 1 from dual
 13    union all
 14    select 4, 6, 5 from dual
 15    union all
 16    select 4, 5, 6 from dual
 17    union all
 18    select 5, 4, 6 from dual
 19    union all
 20    select 5, 6, 4 from dual
 21  )
 22  select a,
 23         b,
 24         c
 25    from (
 26      select a,
 27             b,
 28             c,
 29             min_abc,
 30             middle_abc,
 31             max_abc,
 32             row_number() over( partition by min_abc,
 33                                             middle_abc,
 34                                             max_abc
 35                                    order by a,
 36                                             b,
 37                                             c ) rn
 38        from (
 39          select (case when a not in (min_abc, max_abc)
 40                       then a
 41                       when b not in (min_abc, max_abc)
 42                       then b
 43                       else c
 44                    end) middle_abc,
 45                 min_abc,
 46                 max_abc,
 47                 a,
 48                 b,
 49                 c
 50            from (
 51              select least(a, b, c) min_abc,
 52                     greatest(a,b,c) max_abc,
 53                     a,
 54                     b,
 55                     c
 56                from x ) get_min_max
 57          ) get_middle
 58    ) get_rn
 59*  where rn = 1
SQL> /

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         4          5          6
```

Comment: @Emerald214 - I'm not sure what you mean.  Both of these options are a single SQL statement.

Comment: I tried the second solution, MySQLsays "syntax error near 'partition by min_abc, middle_abc, max_abc order by a, b, c) rn"

Comment: @Emerald214 - Sorry about that.  You didn't mention that you were using MySQL until you updated the tags 2 hours ago so I didn't use a MySQL-specific solutions.  Most relational databases these days support analytic functions but MySQL does not.  You can emulate analytic functions in MySQL http://oreilly.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html but it complicates the query rather substantially.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution is buggy. Try this instead:

```
select distinct
       least(a,b,c) as min,
       case least(a,b,c)
       when a then least(b,c)
       when b then least(a,c)
       else least(a,b)
       end as mid,
       greatest(a,b,c) as max
from foo;
```

Comment: the output was wrong: 
(min   mid   max)
( 1     NULL  3)
( 4     NULL  6)

Comment: my bad, mysql behaves differently from postgresql on least/greatest and nulls. updating the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the sum of a set of numbers is not dependent on ordering:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM foo
GROUP BY SUM(a, b, c)
```